# Gradle sync failed: Unsupported class file major version

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, build.gradle

Gradle sync failed: Unsupported class file major version 60 (13 m 44 s 731 ms)

Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\umer\AppData\Local\Temp\ijresolvers.gradle' (C:\Users\umer.gradle\caches\6.7.1\scripts\c6td7o6d0dhgcyioq91fpl38q).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.cache.CacheOpenException: Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\umer\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle'

  (C:\Users\umer.gradle\caches\6.7.1\scripts\32yvt2zeehsxo3nh051fqju98).
  at

Comment: JAVA_HOME  =  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1

Comment: Path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: C:\Users\umer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

Comment: %ANDROID_HOME%\tools

Answer (score 3):

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301

use jdk1.8.0_301
not use jdk-16.0.1

Add all PATHs(Flutter, Java, Android SDK, system, VS Code(Visual Studio Code) etc.)

Error Resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check the gradle compatibility matrix - and choose the right gradle for the right jdk version.

| Java version | First Gradle version to support it |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 2.0 |
| 9 | 4.3 |
| 10 | 4.7 |
| 11 | 5.0 |
| 12 | 5.4 |
| 13 | 6.0 |
| 14 | 6.3 |
| 15 | 6.7 |
| 16 | 7.0 |
| 17 | 7.3 |
| 18 | 7.5 |
| 19 | 7.6 |

Source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html?_ga=2.43774181.1197148843.1684572075-1263589957.1665469528